# VB.NET repeater grouping by months

Tags: vb.net, repeater

My repeater is searching through dates in the SQL Server database and returning the first 3 letters of every month. Is there a way to show the repeater the way I want to?

```
<asp:repeater id="rptLetters" runat="server" datasourceid="dsLetters">
<headertemplate>
|
</headertemplate>
<itemtemplate>
<asp:linkbutton id="btnLetter" runat="server" onclick="btnLetter_Click" text='<%#Eval("Letter")%>' />
</itemtemplate>

<separatortemplate>
|
</separatortemplate>
</asp:repeater>

 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLetters" runat="server" Visible="False"  DataSourceID="dsLetters">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:sqldatasource id="dsLetters" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$  
 ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString %>"  
   selectcommand="SELECT DISTINCT LEFT       
   (p.LaunchDate, 3) AS [Letter] 
   FROM Product p, Category c 
   WHERE c.ParentID = 37 
   AND p.LaunchDate IS NOT NULL">
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

Shows up as: ALL | Apr | Aug | Dec | Feb | Jan | Jul | Jun | Mar | May | Nov | Oct | Sep

Would like: ALL | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec

Comment: Order By the month of p.LaunchDate in your query.

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni I tried `SELECT DISTINCT LEFT (p.LaunchDate, 3) AS [Letter] FROM Product p, Category c WHERE c.ParentID = 37 AND p.LaunchDate IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Month(p.LaunchDate), Day(p.LaunchDate) ASC` but SQL Server says `ORDER BY items must be appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.` so I take out DISTINCT and then it has multiples of all the months.

Comment: Ah, right, distinct. Two thoughts: first, why are you abusing the database server to get the names of months? Are they going to change? This is going to force at least an index scan, if not a table scan, of Product in order to extract the names of months. You're dangerously close to TheDailyWTF land with that...

Second: if you MUST do this, then do an inner query with the order by and an outer query to mangle the month names. 

I would suggest instead that you either bind to an array or don't bother binding for this.

Comment: Well I could just put the names in the repeater and select the dates from the database based on the month in the repeater. I think I got the idea for the repeater from a post on the ASP.net forum. That's the only reason I did it this way. I don't want to end up on that website, I've seen some of the craziness that goes on there....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ditched the repeater idea, and am just using linkbuttons to list the months. My SQL query will then find results based on which month is clicked.

```
<asp:linkbutton id="btnAll" runat="server" text="ALL" onclick="btnAll_Click" /> |
<asp:linkbutton id="btnJan" runat="server" text="Jan" onclick="btnMonths_Click" /> |
<asp:linkbutton id="btnFeb" runat="server" text="Feb" onclick="btnMonths_Click" /> |
<asp:linkbutton id="btnMar" runat="server" text="Mar" onclick="btnMonths_Click" /> |
<asp:linkbutton id="btnApr" runat="server" text="Apr" onclick="btnMonths_Click" /> |
<asp:linkbutton id="btnMay" runat="server" text="May" onclick="btnMonths_Click" /> |
<asp:linkbutton id="btnJune" runat="server" text="June" onclick="btnMonths_Click" /> |
<asp:linkbutton id="btnJuly" runat="server" text="July" onclick="btnMonths_Click" /> |
<asp:linkbutton id="btnAug" runat="server" text="Aug" onclick="btnMonths_Click" /> |
<asp:linkbutton id="btnSep" runat="server" text="Sep" onclick="btnMonths_Click" /> |
<asp:linkbutton id="btnOct" runat="server" text="Oct" onclick="btnMonths_Click" /> |
<asp:linkbutton id="btnNov" runat="server" text="Nov" onclick="btnMonths_Click" /> |
<asp:linkbutton id="btnDec" runat="server" text="Dec" onclick="btnMonths_Click" />



SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductName, p.LaunchDate 
FROM Product p JOIN CategoryLink l 
ON p.ProductID = l.ProductID 
JOIN Category c ON c.CategoryID = l.CategoryID 
WHERE(p.LaunchDate LIKE '{0}%') 
AND c.ParentID = '37' 
AND p.ProductName IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY Month(p.LaunchDate), Day(p.LaunchDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite advising against it above, this demonstrates how to handle the need to order on a dependency before extracting distinct:

```
select distinct left(launchdate,3) as Abbreviated from
(   select * from product 
    where launchdate is not null order by month(launchdate) asc) p,     
category c where c.parentid=@ParentId
```

For this particular case, you should not use a query to extract the month abbreviations assuming that the default date-to-string conversion will let your left 3 characters be an accurate month abbreviation.

Comment: Using this query, I get the result `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.`
Is there a way of using the repeater WITHOUT it being database driven? I know you said the way I was trying to use the repeater isn't best practice, but I'm still learning so I would appreciate more feedback if possible. Thank you very much for your help.